# Angular Grouped ngFor Not Displaying Values

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I'm attempting to create an accordion that is grouped to show a list of sessions that are grouped by levels.

I created a pipe which I've checked with a console log and is outputting the data with a key and values. However When I try to show this in the UI I just get blank values as if there were no data.

How can I get the actual values to display inside the accordion? I've tried a few different variations such as `{{session.SessionTitle}}` and `{{session.value.SessionTitle}}`, but neither seemed to have worked.

HTML:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card" *ngFor="let session of sessions | groupSessionByLevel:'LevelName'">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          {{session.key}}
          <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block">{{session.value.SessionOrder}}. {{session.value.SessionTitle}}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'groupSessionByLevel'
})
export class GroupSessionByLevelPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(collection: any, property: string): any {
    // prevents the application from breaking if the array of objects doesn't exist yet
    if(!collection) {
        return null;
    }

    const groupedCollection = collection.reduce((previous, current)=> {
        if(!previous[current[property]]) {
            previous[current[property]] = [current];
        } else {
            previous[current[property]].push(current);
        }

        return previous;
    }, {});

    // this will return an array of objects, each object containing a group of objects
    return Object.keys(groupedCollection).map(key => ({ key, value: groupedCollection[key] }));
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the returned object's value from your `GroupSessionByLevelPipe` pipe, you have an array. If you add `ngFor` in your body you'll see your desired buttons.

```
<div class="card-body" *ngFor="let sessionValue of session.value">
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block">{{sessionValue.SessionOrder}}. {{sessionValue.SessionTitle}}</button>
</div>
```

> You can see this in this [StackBlitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-groupby) I've created

You can see in this project, that I get an array in the returned grouped object's value.